# Google Maps API Android setting up last location errors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

So I have attempted to follow the tutorial for the last location as seen here
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

To which I am not getting a marker being added to the fragment which would suggest that the marker is updating correctly. I have tried this on my main project and it doesn't work. So i tried to follow the tutorial to the letter on a brand new project to see if i could remove the problem .

I was wondering if this was a problem with the emulator I am using (definitely using the google API version of 6.0) since i am not being able to run a sample project correctly either

below are the files that I have used and the error log that is produces
MapTesting.java

```
package dominic.maptesting;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 private Location mLastLocation;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
  // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

  if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .build();

  }

 }

 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // TODO: Consider calling
   //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
   // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
   //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
   //                                          int[] grantResults)
   // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
   // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
   return;
  }
  mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
   mGoogleApiClient);
  if (mLastLocation != null) {
   LatLng test = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test).title("Marker Test"));
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));

  } else {}

 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

 }

 protected void onStart() {
  mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  super.onStart();
 }

 protected void onStop() {
  mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
  super.onStop();
 }


 @Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

 }

 @Override
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

 }
}
```

Activity_Map.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="dominic.maptesting.MapsActivity" />
```

AppManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="dominic.maptesting">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
01-26 17:21:51.228 3427-3427/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-26 17:21:51.228 3427-3427/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-26 17:21:51.255 1299-1339/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b6f8f72 dominic.maptesting/dominic.maptesting.MapsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-26 17:21:51.991 959-959/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
01-26 17:21:53.175 3440-3440/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-26 17:21:53.175 3440-3440/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-26 17:21:53.244 3436-3436/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-26 17:21:53.244 3436-3436/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-26 17:21:53.725 1598-1872/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4093960
01-26 17:21:54.666 948-2693/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated . Am pretty stuck with this and am a novice with android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you carefully see following block of code is causing the issue.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // TODO: Consider calling
   //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
   // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
   //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
   //                                          int[] grantResults)
   // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
   // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
   return;
  }
```

On Android 6.0 this block will return true and function will just exit without executing further code.The reason is you are targeting android 6.0 version and you are not handling runtime permissions. Please go through this article to get understanding on Android Runtime permissions.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions

Still after using Runtime permission you might not see markers on map because `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` might just return null so you will have to handle that logic as well.

Comment: having attempted that tutorial on runtime permissions I'm still not getting any markers being added even with the handling of getLastLocation being null. any ideas http://pastebin.com/TQk8Fjny